# Javascript indexOf('&#8377;') for IndianRupee character & the like, not working

Tags: javascript

I'm having a dropdown with options text in the below format on my webpage-(₹ renders the Indian Rupee character)

```
<option value = "101">Notebook (&#8377;25)</option>
<option value = "102">Pen (&#8377;5)</option>
```

In Javascript function, I get the option text and try to extract only the price from it, using substring and indexOf.

`var optionString = $('#stationeryList').find('option:selected').text();` //This is "Pen (₹5)"

```
alert(optionString.indexOf('&#8377;'));  // returns -1
```

How to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression?

Comment: Try `optionString.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(8377))` or `optionString.indexOf('\u20B9')` or `optionString.indexOf('₹')`.

Comment: Problem: `var div = document.createElement('div');div.innerHTML = 'Notebook (&#8377;25)';var txt = div.innerHTML;console.log(txt.indexOf('&#8377;') === -1)`

Comment: [Surprising](https://jsfiddle.net/anw4zqch/), tbqh.

Comment: @melpomene : Thanks for quick reply. It worked perfectly. I opted for optionString.indexOf('\u20B9') from your alternatives. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the amount using the following regex:

```
var value = "Pen (₹5)";
var amountMatcherRegex = new RegExp('.*\\(' + String.fromCharCode(8377) + '(\\d+)\\)','g');
var matches = amountMatcherRegex.exec(value);
if(matches && matches[1]) {
     alert(matches[1]);
}
```